# Starpattern in console app

Tags: c#

I need to create the following pattern: 
[image: http://puu.sh/dx3fN/500f5ee468.png]

It is homework, this question I failed the first time.
I read now that I should have only used "*" one time, but how would this even work in that case?
Would appreciate if anyone could give me some insight in how to think.

My code is down below:

```
using System;
class StarPattern
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        for (int a = 0; a <= 0; a++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        for (int c = 0; c <= 0; c++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   *");
        }
        for (int d = 0; d <= 1; d++ )
        {
            Console.Write("*");
            Console.WriteLine("   *");
        }
        for (int e = 0; e < 5; e++ )
        {
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }                 
}
```

Comment: Should they be nested?

Comment: Try using a double for loop.

Comment: Think about it logically. How many stars do you need to print on each line? Which lines? (What was your feedback when you failed?)

Comment: Thanks for stating honestly "It is homework"!

Comment: You could add the `*` as a const and use that. Technically you'd be using only 1 `*`

Comment: I'd go with `Console.WriteLine("*****\n*   *\n*   *\n*   *\n*****\n");`. Seriously. If the box 5x5 is only requirement as it's presented.

Comment: @luk32 -- He can only use the `*` once. But what he could do is `Console.WriteLine("!!!!!\n! !\n! !\n! !\n!!!!!\n".Replace("!", "*"));`

Comment: Please do not delete your orginal question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simplify your code by nesting loops so outer (`i`) = rows and inner (`j`) = columns.  From looking at your sample, you want to write out if you're on the boundary of either so you can add a condition to just write out on min and max.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == 4 || j == 0 || j == 4)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I'd probably replace 0 with a constant called MIN and 4 with a constant called MAX to save duplicating them.  That way, you could increase the size of the square by just changing the constants.

Answer (score 5):

Hardly anyone is commenting their code for you. How disappointing!

The trick here is to focus on what is important and define values that you will;

1. be using many times in the code
2. only want to change once if requirements need tweeking

These values are **height** and **width** - the core components of a rectangle.

The golden rule for the pattern is: **If the row and column of each character is on the edge of the square, print a `*`**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Stars
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Width = 5; //define the width of the square in characters
        static int Height = 5; //define the height of the square in characters

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row <= Height; row++) //Each iteration here is one row.
            {
                //loop representing columns. This is NESTED within the rows so 
                //that each row prints more than one column
                for (int column = 0; column <= Width; column++)
                {
                    if (IsCentreOfSquare(row, column)) //calculate if the current row and column coordinates are the interior of the square
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(); //this row is over. move to the next row
            }
            Console.ReadLine(); //pause so that the user can admire the pretty picture.
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates if the row and column indexes specified are in the interior of the square pattern
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static bool IsCentreOfSquare(int row, int col)
        {
            if (row > 0 && row < Height)
            {
                if (col > 0 && col < Width)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have an upvote for abstracting the logic into a single sentence and then implement it in a method, but all your inline comments are redundant. They literally state what the line of code before them does. You use meaningful variable names for that, e.g. `row` instead of `i`. Use comments explaining _why_ you do something if that isn't clear from reading the code. You could for example invert the `CentreSquare` logic and rename it to `ShouldPrintStar`.

Comment: Comments in code are not for _beginning developers_ to understand the code. If you think so, you should also explain `for` and `if`.

Comment: @CodeCaster point taken on the variable naming. Expanded comments a little and renamed method to be easier on the brain.

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill for such a simple program, but make it scalable and add some `const int`s to make the design able to be modified whenever you'd like!
Good question. It's fun to feel like I'm tutoring again! Glad to see you at least gave it an honest attempt :)

```
class Program
{
    // Use string if you are okay with breaking the current pattern.
    // private static string myDesign = "*";
    // Use char if you want to ensure the integrity of your pattern.
    private static char myDesign = '*';
    private const int COLUMN_COUNT = 5;
    private const int ROW_COUNT = 5;
    private const int FIRST_ROW = 0;
    private const int LAST_ROW = 4;
    private const int FIRST_COLUMN = 0;
    private const int LAST_COLUMN = 4;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Iterate through the desired amount of rows.
        for (int row = 0; row < ROW_COUNT; row++)
        {
            // Iterate through the desired amount of columns.
            for (int column = 0; column < COLUMN_COUNT; column++)
            {
                // If it is your first or last column or row, then write your character.
                if (column == FIRST_COLUMN || column == LAST_COLUMN || row == FIRST_ROW || row == LAST_ROW)
                {
                    Console.Write(myDesign);
                }
                // If anywhere in between provide your blank character.
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to make `myDesign` a `char`, else your program is subject to failure.

Comment: Not exactly. What if you wanted your design to be "*#7#*", then a `char` would cause program failure. `string` is safer in this program considering the op didn't specify this being a `char` field.

Comment: Yes, but your drawing will be broken.

Comment: Ah, I understand where you're coming from. You're saying it will 'break' if you want to keep the desired star pattern. This is true. I'm just saying this will at least print any design you provide.

Comment: No, it will break if you use `@@@`. Give it a try.

Comment: Nope, ran just fine. It spelled out OC. :p

Comment: I think @PatrickHofman means it'll no longer be a square/rectangle

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Right, that's what I was trying to say in the previous commment of mine. Lol.

Comment: There, I clarified that in the code, so OP won't get confused.

Answer (score 1):

It is not that difficult to do.  You need to create two loops: one for the rows and one for the columns and then determine whether to print a star or not.  Only the first and the last rows and columns have a star.

In my example I use two counters that start from 0 and count to 4.  If the remainder of either counter value divided by 4 equals to 0 then I print a star, otherwise a space.

```
using System;

namespace Stars
{
  internal static class StarPattern
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
          Console.Write((i%4 == 0) | (j%4 == 0) ? '*' : ' ');
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print a certain number of lines with a certain sequence of characters per line.

One approach would be to create or find a method that prints whatever character sequence you need. Then create a method to sequence calls to to that. Finally, print the result of all that.

```
private void PrintBox(char c, int width, int height)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    result.Add(new string(c, width)); // First line

    for (var i = 0; i < height - 2; i++)
    {
        string iLine;
        int spaceCount = width - 2;
        iLine = new string(c, 1) + new string(' ', spaceCount) + new string(c, 1);
        result.Add(iLine);
    }

    result.Add(new string(c, width)); // Last line

    // FYI, there's a StringBuilder class that makes all this easier

    foreach (var line in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

The important OOP concept here is that we made use of a single reusable method for constructing a sequence of characters - new string(char, int). If we wanted to create a Circle, we could create a BuildCircle method based on the same principle.

Comment: That repeat function can be simply replaced by **new string(c, count)**